# Minecraft 1.12 turn off tutorial/instructions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft 1.12 and onwards, on the top right hand corner of the screen, a tutorial pops up telling the player what to do. It doesn't go away until the player does what it says.

[image]

This is undesirable for server admins like me as well as some of my fellow players, for they are simply annoying and kind of useless, especially when the tutorial tells you to break a tree but the entire map in the server cannot be edited.

Is there any way to disable them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a way to turn it off for MC 1.12+, but it can only be turned off client side (meaning players need to disable it themselves).

**Warning**: Make sure you have your minecraft closed for this to work.

1. Find your **.minecraft** folder  and open it. Type **%appdata%** in the search bar on the left bottom corner if you don't know where your **.minecraft** folder is located.
2. Next, find the file called "**options**" or "**options.txt**" and open it.
3. Search for "**tutorialStep:**" in the options file. Quick way to find it is by pushing these keys on your keyboard **CTRL + F** and typing **tutorial** in the search box.
4. Replace "**tutorialStep:*(anything that was written here, delete it)***" with "**tutorialStep:none**".
5. **Save the file**, launch your Minecraft game, and enter a multiplayer server or single player world to check if you did it correctly.

That's it.

Still having trouble? Here's a [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DH8AsV2IhMk) made by someone on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

These popups are called **Tutorial Hints**. According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.12), they should only appear once per device.  That means if you complete them on a single player world, they should not come back for as long as you use that computer.

Other than that, there is no other way to get rid of them in-game, but even then, there should be no real reason to disable them before you start.